# Chromedriver on Heroku/Rails: Unable to load application: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: not a file: "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the error above when trying to run Selenium on Heroku, RoR app.

I've added the buildpacks heroku-buildpack-google-chrome and heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

Then added the config variables

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

And added this code on the capybara setup:

```
chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)

chrome_opts = chrome_bin ? { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_bin } } : {}


Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
     app,
     browser: :chrome,
     desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_opts),   ) end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

As described on the chrome link: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

Do I need to set up another variable for the location of the webdriver? If yes, how? and how do I assign it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having this same issue

Comment: same issue, have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this working on heroku rails app by using the following:

1) added the buildpacks heroku-buildpack-google-chrome and heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

2) set the driver in rails

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
if Rails.env.production?
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = ENV["GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM"]
end
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

No need to set any ENV variables on heroku as GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM is set automatically by the webdriver build package.